# Create a background pattern with css

Tags: css

I have a design made with figma:
[image]

I have the shapes svg, I want to create the same design to be a background for my website.
Is it possible to do with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVGs are a valid file type for the CSS url function.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;

  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: yes, but I have each vector seperated, how can I put them together